# How to Auto scale AWS EKS instance based on the kafka queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, autoscalemode

I need to Auto scale instance of AWS (kubernates instance) based on the kafka queue through which I'm publishing the messages.

Comment: post here what you tried till now and where you got stuck, so that we can help you out.

Comment: you have option of using KEDA which is Kubernetes event driven auto scaling, it does support Kafka. https://keda.sh/docs/2.5/scalers/apache-kafka/